# Multiple controllers, two "depths" of relationships

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, multiple-tables

I'm writing my first app in Ruby on Rails (I've only went through railstutorial.org before ) which is simple Electronic Prescription Service and I run on one thing I can't cope with.

I want to create form for adding new prescription as well as adding some medicines which belong to this newly created prescription.

First problem is - how can I actually add medicines to the prescription when during filling the form prescription doesn't exist yet? What I did before was I first create prescription with `@user.prescription.create(presc_attributes)` and later `@prescription.relations.create(medicine_id)`.

Now I need to do this probably on one form sending the whole thing using one button ( one HTML request, am I right? ) unless you guys have got better idea. I'm also struggling with an idea where to actually put method creating this prescription. Should it be in PrescriptionController#new or maybe connected to RelationsController#new as well?

I've read couple of articles about nested fields_for but they don't seem to match exactly what I need.

Im really new to RoR so sorry if I missed something important.

Here is my EER as well
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa9CB.png

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE---

ahhh i see, I think what you want is a relationship with an inverse_of.

If you are using a belongs_to on the join model, it is a good idea to set the :inverse_of option on the belongs_to, which will mean that the following example works correctly (where tags is a has_many :through association):

```
@post = Post.first
@tag = @post.tags.build name: "ruby"
@tag.save
```

The last line ought to save the through record (a Taggable). This will only work if the :inverse_of is set:

```
class Taggable < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :tag, inverse_of: :taggings
end
```

If you do not set the :inverse_of record, the association will do its best to match itself up with the correct inverse. Automatic inverse detection only works on has_many, has_one, and belongs_to associations.

FROM http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: The thing is I already got table medicines that is filled with medicines names, doses etc. When creating new prescription I dont want to CREATE medicine, i just want to create relations connecting certain prescription with certain medicine so I am not sure if `@medicine = @prescription.medicines.new(medicine_params)` is correct

Comment: ahhh i see, I think what you want is a relationship with an inverse_of. Altered my answer to reflect this. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I finally managed to do this using nested_attributes. Now I'm struggling with another problem tho http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23461902/rails4-autocomplete-form-with-multiple-inputs-html-data-id-element-overwritten